# Calling Object Methods in Underscore.compose

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Using the Underscore `_.compose` method, is it possible to invoke object methods in the composition and set the context to the object that owns the method being invoked?

```
example: function(data) {
  return _.compose(
    ObjectOne.methodName,
    ObjectTwo.methodName
  )(data);
}
```

When `ObjectOne.methodName()` is executed, I want `this` to be `ObjectOne`. However, I'm getting `Window` as the context in both method calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), like this

```
example: function(data) {
  return _.compose(
    ObjectOne.methodName.bind(ObjectOne),
    ObjectTwo.methodName.bind(ObjectTwo)
  )(data);
}
```

The `bind` call will return a new function object, with the argument you pass as the context object.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks for the quick response. Will accept momentarily.